# Configuring Apache to work with Angular and express in localhost HTTPS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, apache, ubuntu

I have problems making angular (running in apache) communicating with my express server (running on pm2 port 3000), both are on the same ubuntu machine communicating in https.
If i make the angular 'talk' with the apis through https://sitename:3000/v1/ everything works fine, but when i turn that address to https://localhost:3000/v1/ nothing works.

I would expect angular to communicate with the backend throught localhost, leaving the port 3000 of the site closed.

Angular requests are going through:
`public static readonly API_ENDPOINT: string = 'https://sitename/v1/';`

I have tried to use apache proxy with no success, here are my apache configurations:
000-default host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sitename
        ServerAlias sitename
    Redirect permanent / https://sitename/
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sitename
        ServerAlias sitename
        Redirect permanent / https://sitename/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName sitename
   ServerAlias sitename
   ProxyPass /v1 http://localhost:3000/v1/
   ProxyPassReverse /v1 http://localhost:3000/v1/
   DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend
   <Directory "/var/www/frontend">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   </Directory>
   Protocols h2 http/1.1
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /..../.../cert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /.../.../key.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile /.../.../csr.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i have an .htaccess file inside my /var/www/frontend

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [QSA,L]
```

Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: What error message do you get?